# How can I animate border-radius of li element with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I just started doing some jquery and php and I followed the tutorial from Udemy on how to build some php web site. Now I want to animate the li elements so that their border-radius changes on mouseenter().

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list_el').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate(borderRadius(300), 200);
  });

  function borderRadius(radius) {
    return {
      borderTopLeftRadius: radius,
      borderTopRightRadius: radius,
      borderBottomLeftRadius: radius,
      borderBottomRightRadius: radius,
    };
  }
});
```

```css
#nav {
  margin: -27px 0 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  background: #353535;
  outline: solid 2px #353535;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #8ca757;
  outline: solid 2px #8ca757;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="my_navbar">
    <li class="list_el"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="team.php">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But when I enter the mouse on any of the li element (menu,contact..) it doesn't animate, I mean when I press F12 and target the li it shows me that the border-radius is changing but on the website it doesn't curve the border. So what am I doing wrong?

Just in case :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation works, it just has no visual effect: your a elements contains all the style, you'll see some change if you animate the a's border-radius or if you put overflow: hidden for list_el

```
$('.list_el').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).find("a").animate(borderRadius(300), 200);
});
```

this will work for instance

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGPrgY

Comment: Please keep examples on-site using Stack Snippets.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, I didn't know that, but yeah viusal effect was missing and was a bit confused.

Can u explain me how can I make it so it doesn't target just the "a" element but the whole box, so that it rounds the whole box instead of just the inside of it? @Axnyff

Comment: Maybe you should try and move the style for your link to the li container

Answer (score 0):

You should use mouse enter and leave event together

```
$('.list_el').on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).find("a").animate(borderRadius(300), 200);
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
         $(this).find("a").animate(borderRadius(0), 200);
});
```

Comment: I was planing to add the mouseleave too, but the problem was that I didn't target the "a" element I guess, thanks a lot btw :) @Ish

Answer (score 0):

On any modern browser, you can also achieve this transition with simply:

```
.list_el:hover a {
  border-radius: 300px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

That animates the `border-radius` of the contained `a` element over a period of 200ms when the `.list_el` containing the `a` is hovered.

Note that this assumes you were planning to add a `mouseleave` handler that undoes the border-radius. It doesn't apply if you were planning to leave the updated radius in place when the mouse leaves the element.

Example using `1s` rather than `0.2s` so it's more obvious:

```css
#nav {
  margin: -27px 0 0;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 44px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
#nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
  border: solid 2px white;
  background: #353535;
  outline: solid 2px #353535;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #8ca757;
  outline: solid 2px #8ca757;
}
.list_el:hover a {
  border-radius: 300px;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="my_navbar">
    <li class="list_el"><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="team.php">Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="menu.php">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list_el"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help.

I wanted to do it with jquery for practice and I was going to add the mouseleave() too. I was looking on how to animate the whole box instead of just the "a" element and I guess that beacuse of that I wasn't getting any visual effect. @T.J. Crowder